# Need Help With My Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

This Trigger is for After Insert , After Update and After Delete
So basically I have `Opportunity` and `OpportunityLineItem` So basically what this Trigger do is calculate custom created fields in the `Opportunity` Object based on the fields of the `OpportunityLineItem` This trigger handler is already working like it calculates when added,deleted or even when I edit the `OpportunityLineItem`. Now my problem is when I delete all the `OpportunityLineItem` in the `Opportunity` the custom created fields like for example the Total_List_Price__c in the `Opportunity` object is not updating. Can Someone help me with this one.

This is my Trigger Handler Code

```
public class TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler {



public void TotalField(List<OpportunityLineItem> o){


   Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();

// First step, loop over your Opp Line Items to figure out exactly which Opportunities
//   we are working with.
for(OpportunityLineItem oli :o){
    opportunityIds.add(oli.OpportunityId);
}

List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT OpportunityId,
        SUM(ListPrice) TotalListPrice, SUM(Recommended_end_user_price__c) TotalEndUserPrice, AVG(SPR_Discount__c) TotalSPRDiscount,
        SUM(SPR_Price__c) totalSPRPrice, SUM(TotalPrice) totalPrice, AVG(Distributor_SPR_Margin__c) totalSPRMargin
    FROM OpportunityLineItem 
    WHERE OpportunityId IN :opportunityIds 
    GROUP BY OpportunityId]){

        oppsToUpdate.add(new Opportunity(

            Id = (Id)ar.get('OpportunityId'),


            Total_List_Price__c = ar.get('TotalListPrice') == null ? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('TotalListPrice'),
            Total_End_User_Price__c = ar.get('TotalEndUserPrice') == null? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('TotalEndUserPrice'),
            Total_Standard_Price_Discount__c = ar.get('TotalSPRDiscount') == null? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('TotalSPRDiscount'),
            Total_SPR_Price__c = ar.get('totalSPRPrice') == null? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('totalSPRPrice'),
            Total_Price__c = ar.get('totalPrice') == null? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('totalPrice'),
            Total_SPR_Margin__c = ar.get('totalSPRMargin') == null? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('totalSPRMargin')
        ));
}

update oppsToUpdate;

         for(Opportunity oppor : oppsToUpdate  ){
         oppor.Total_End_User_Price_Discount__c = (1 - oppor.Total_End_User_Price__c / oppor.Total_List_Price__c) * 100;
         oppor.Total_SPR_Price_Discount__c = (1 - oppor.Total_SPR_Price__c / oppor.Total_List_Price__c) * 100;
         oppor.Total_Price_Discount__c = (1 - oppor.Total_Price__c / oppor.Total_List_Price__c) * 100;
         }  
 update  oppsToUpdate; 



    }

}
```

Comment: You should just use `Rollup Summary Fields` here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Well basically the reason why I did not use roll up summary fields is because. The user can choose to activate or deactive this trigger, Well basically the user has two choices whether he want's to auto calculate the fields in the Opportunity object or the user is the one who input data to those fields.

Comment: Then use a combination of Rollup and Custom field and user would be able to deactivate the Workflow populating Custom field value if he prefers to update it manually.

Comment: Actually my code is working from above and I am just following instructions, I just need to update the custom fields from Opportunity if there is no OpportunityLineItem. I just need to Add something from my code. Thanks for the reply.